# C++ I don't want to ignore white spaces in folder paths (MAC) how can I do that?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am currently working on a project which runs pretty well, and I get a file path from the user, if the path has no white spaces it works pretty well! but if it includes white spaces the system ignores and doesn't continue reading the path. For Ex; if the path says **Desktop/School Projects/C++**
System reads only the **Desktop/School** part and ignores the rest of it. how can I fix that!

I am pretty sure its because I used `char directory[256];` instead of `string directory;` to get the path, but string doesn't work for the rest of the code because `system(command);` function works only with const char* and if I even use string var it translates string to char! so I donno what to do right now. I cant just ask user to create folders without spaces...

Comment: Why have to added the C language tag for your C++ question? C is a totally different language from C++.

Comment: And any decent book, tutorial or class should have told you about [the `c_str()` function of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str). Use `std::string` everywhere, and only get a pointer to the contained string just when you need it. Like in `std::string command; /* Initialization of command... */ system(command.c_str());`

Comment: When you use `system` to execute a command, the command string is passed to a command-line shell that interprets it. Command-line shells typically interpret spaces as separations between different parts of the command. For example, `ls -l foo bar` means execute the `ls` command with option `-l` on the files `foo` and `bar`, not execute the `ls -l` command on the single file `foo bar`. To include spaces in paths in commands, you need to quote them, that is, to enclose them in quotation marks or use other techniques to tell the shell that the spaces are part of the file name…

Comment: … A simple method for this is to enclose the path in quotes. `ls -l "foo bar"` means execute the `ls` command with option `-l` on the single file `foo bar`. However, to do this correctly, you need to handle all special characters that can be in paths, such as quote characters, new-line characters, non-printable characters, characters with special meanings to the command-line shell, and so on. That requires a fair bit of work and understanding of the shell’s processing of command lines.

Comment: Generally, it is rare that a program should do anything with the `system` command. You should use the standard C++ features for manipulating files.

Comment: (By the way, “MAC” is an abbreviation for various phrases with the initial letters M, A, and C, such as a Media Access Control address. An Apple computer is a Macintosh or “Mac”.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getline(cin, directory);` instead of `cin >> directory;` in order to store more than one words in a string, and don't forget to use `cin.ignore();` before `getline`.